# Открытие процесса посредством PHP

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, api

Необходимо реализовать открытие стороннего приложения, после того, как придёт GET (или POST, неважно) запрос от пользователя, далее, это приложение может отработать полностью, либо же должно будет закрыться принудительно, для этого от пользователя приходит уже другой запрос, закрывающий его.

Была идея каким-то образом открыть приложение, запомнить его PID, записать в бд и при принудительном закрытии просто закрывать процесс с данным PID, но не смог найти достаточно информации.

Реализацию не прошу, просто хотя бы подтолкните к решению. Заранее спасибо.

Ubuntu, PHP

Comment: что за приложение?

Comment: Скажу, что оно стороннее и написано было не мной, открытие типа: ./app-name 3 3 600, где 600 - время работы программы, но должна быть возможность закрыть её принудительно

Comment: Ну....Можно накостылить. Скормить Бубунте из `PHP` команды эт элементарно. А вот как получить `PID` процесса.... - `ps aux | grep app-name | grep -v grep`   - где `app-name` - имя вашего приложения. По идее должно прокатить. А дальше....я вижу такой способ - вывод этой команды перенаправляем в, например, `txt` файл, дальше его парсим, и получаем наш `PID`. А с ним уже делаем все что захотим.

Comment: Но это не точно :)

Comment: @NikolayGabaraev, ещё суть в том, что таких "копий" приложения может быть много от разных пользователей, как я понимаю, в таком случае такое не подходит? (не уверен в сказанном :в)

Comment: @ИльяДружинин Можно сделать тогда вот так - 
`app-name 3 3 600 &`   - запускаем приложение, затем `echo $!` - это выведен в консоль PID только что запущенного процесса. (А точнее, последнего запущенного)

Comment: @NikolayGabaraev, странно, но `echo $!` не хочет работать, можешь скинуть ссылку где про это описано?

Comment: `app-name 3 3 600 &` и `echo $!` Должно запускаться в рамках одной сессии что бы получить id процесса, например так`app-name 3 3 600 & echo $!`

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash cntr+F `$!`

Comment: кмк нужно копать в сторону pcntl_fork и posix_kill. Только на shared-хостингах pcntl почти повсеместно отключен. Когда мне потребовалось нечто подобное, оказалось проще взять другой язык (C# в моём случае), чем пытаться добиться от PHP нужного поведения

Comment: Стандартной последовательностью fork()-exec()-kill()-wait() в виде pcntl_fork, pcntl_exec, posix_kill и pcntl_wait?